# ¿Como habilitar y a mis Proveedores activos y no avtivos?

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo una lista de proveedores donde tengo toda su información, lo que quieo es que en mi pagina principal solo aparezcan los activos y cuando se venzca su fecha de proveedor los pueda quitar de mi lista de proveedores sin nesecidad de borrarlos de mi base de datos.

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia. Debes [edit] la publicación para añadir más información como por ejemplo la estructura de las tablas relacionadas, la consulta que realizas para obtener la lista de proveedores y/o el código con el que lo pones todo junto. Lee [ask] para más información, y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es agregar un campo llamado por ejemplo "estado". Si el estado está en 0 (cero), está inactivo, si está en 1(uno), está activo, y generas una consulta para que solo deje ingresar los que están en estado 1. Saludos

(Editado)Si está en SQL puedes hacer esto. De esta manera traes todos los proovedores que estén en estado 1 (activado). Repito, como no indicas que motor de base de datos usas, es díficil decir exactamente como resolverlo, pero creo que podrias así.

```
SELECT * FROM proovedores WHERE proovedores.estado = 1;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué añadir un campo "estado" cuando, según la pregunta, la condición de activo/inactivo se decide por una fecha que (parece) ya existe en la base de datos?

Comment: Raul A. Como haria la consulta? para agregarla a mi codigo, algún ejemplo que tengas

Comment: Hay que aclarar primero que debes tener un script que valide cuales son los que ya venció su fecha de proovedor. Luego de que valides y cambies el estado activo a 0(cero). Simplemente haz una consulta. Aunque no has iindicando que motor usas ni nada similar. Supondré que está en SQL.